# Java charAt method returning values not even part of the string

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, linked-list, radix

I am working on a radix sort lab for my college computer science B course but I keep running into an error. I need to get the value of a digit in a certain spot so to do that I converted the number into a string and used user charAt(2) to get the ones digit of 587. However, charAt is returning 55 which makes no sense and then I get an index out of bounds error because the number is supposed to be one digit from 0-9. the method takes the head of a linkedList, removes it from the linked list and then takes the removed node and adds it into a bucket.

```
  String s = null;
  String val;


    for(int i = 0; i <count;i++){

     int temp = (Integer)tempNode.getValue();

     val = temp+"";

     int dval = (int) val.charAt(mod);

     tempNode =(name.removeFirst(s));

     bucket[dval].addToEnd(tempNode);
     tempNode = name.getHead();

 }
```

Comment: What's the value of `mod`?

Comment: mod is just the index of the number I want. So since its a three digit number and I want the ones place mod = 2 because I want the last number of the integer

Comment: Ascii `7` is `int` 55. Change `int dval = (int) val.charAt(mod);` to `int dval = Character.digit(mod, 10);` for a `7`.

Comment: that returns -1, not sure why.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch means to say `int dval = Character.digit(val.charAt(mod), 10);` :)

Comment: @Mark or `int dval = val.charAt(mod) - '0';`

Comment: Please post the details of the error message you received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing with `(int) val.charAt(mod)` is getting the ascii value of the character, [see this](http://www.asciitable.com/) which is indeed `55` for the character `7`. What you want is `Character.getNumericValue()` to get the numeric value of this character.

```
String str = "7";

System.out.println((int) str.charAt(0)); // Prints 55
System.out.println(Character.getNumericValue(str.charAt(0))); // Prints 7
```

Comment: The principles are correct but Java doesn't use ASCII. It uses the UTF-16 character encoding of the Unicode character set (just like VB4/5/6/A/Script, JavaScript, .NET, …). See [Class Character](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#unicode) for what `charAt`() returns.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you want to decide the `bucket` index (0 to 9) based on the last digit of the `temp` number. Instead of going through the `String` / `charAt` / `getNumericValue()` detour, you can just use the "division rest" operator of Java:

```
int dval = temp % 10;
```

or generalized (if you don't want to stick to exactly 10 buckets):

```
int dval = temp % bucket.length;
```

Just make sure that `temp` doesn't get negative, as then the division rest becomes negative as well :-(. Besides being shorter and less error-prone, the division-rest approach is also a lot faster.

Comment: I initially tried that but the problem arises when I needed the 10's place value because I would get %100 and get 87 from 587

Comment: For the 10s place, you can do `(temp % 100) / 10`. Similar, for the 100s, do  `(temp % 1000) / 100`, and so on.